# tmux conf: run bash command and store in variable

Tags: tmux

I would like to set `date +"%m %d %y"` to a variable in my tmux.conf file to set it to `set-option -g set-titles-string`. How can I store the value of the output of the shell command in tmux.conf and dereference it later?

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, and was able to figure out how. Using what OP wanted as an example, it'd be something like:

```
curr_date='#(date +"%m %d %y")'
set-option -g set-titles-string $curr_date
```